# Can't display AR -Object continously

Tags: unity-game-engine, easyar

I'm trying to build an AR application with easyAR unity. When running the AR app, the camera gets the image successfully and the AR object displays correctly on first attempt, but when I try on the second attempt, the object didn't show up, what should i do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your debugging attempts? i.e. show some code, logging places where image detection is likely to occur.

Comment: Vuforia is the easiest and most effective augmented reality tool for Unity, it's simple to create AR applications in very simple steps.
try this tutorial if you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6f0PIc6A2Y&t=342s